# How to associate using aireplay-ng?

Tags: wifi, airmon-ng

Reaver fails to associate with the AP, and guides online say to use aireplay-ng to associate first but none have been very specific with exactly how to associate.

I have been doing this sequence of commands:

```
sudo airmon-ng start wlan0
sudo airodump-ng mon0 
sudo reaver -i mon0 -b [ap's mac] -vv
```

I have three routers at home. On one router, using the above commands, it associates, attempt to crack the pin, fails to associate several times in a row, then keeps trying to crack the pin in this cycle. It gets to a grand total of 0.00%. The other two routers always fail to associate altogether.

How to associate with aireplay-ng so I can then use reaver? I made sure my network card is capable of doing monitor mode

Comment: if the server is susceptible then it will show up with sudo wash -i mon0 -C -s (wash comes with reaver). If not then your ap is not attackble via that method.

Answer (score 2):

If you see fails to associate several times in a row after 30 seconds or more then reaver is not associating properly with the router. It really needs more code to make it work like `aireplay-ng`. To get around the problem run `aireplay-ng -1 0 mon0 -a 1A:AD:B9:AD:7E:5E` whatever your ap no. Is every 30 seconds to re-associate with the router before reaver fails.

Also you need to start reaver with the `-c 11` or whatever it is and `-A`. Do not associate with the AP flag as you are now using `aireplay-ng` to do that.

Start a watch in another shell like so

```
. watch -n1  command

.watch -n30  aireplay-ng -1 0 mon0 -a 1A:AD:B9:AD:7E:5E
```